# Is it possible to have a HTML SELECT/OPTION value as NULL using PHP?

Tags: php, html-select

The following is a snippet from my HTML form which pulls the options from the table rows accordingly.

What I want to do is have the first option value to be NULL so when no choice is made, NULL is entered when the form is submitted to the database.

```
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><select name="type_id" id="type_id" class="form">
    <option value=""></option>
        <?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT type_id, type FROM $tbl_add_type") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$row['type_id'].">" . $row['type'] . "</option>";
                }
        ?>
    </select>*</td>
```

Is this possible? Or could someone suggest an easier/better way of doing this?

Thanks

Update: Thanks for the answer, I'm using the method detailed below to convert it to NULL.

```
if ($_POST['location_id'] === '')
                    {
                        $_POST['location_id'] = 'NULL';
                    }
```

However when trying to use this NULL value with the following query it does not work.

```
UPDATE addresses SET location_id='NULL' WHERE ipid = '4791'
```

I know it needs to be `location_id=NULL` instead but don't know how to do this...

Update 2: this is how my queries work:

```
if ($_POST['location_id'] === '')
{
$_POST['location_id'] = 'NULL'; // or 'NULL' for SQL
}

$notes=isset($_POST['notes']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']) : '';
//$location_id=isset($_POST['location_id']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location_id']) : '';
$ipid=isset($_POST['ipid']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipid']) : '';


$sql="UPDATE addresses 
    SET notes='$notes', location_id='$location_id'
    WHERE ipid = '$ipid'";


mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, POST/GET values are never `null`. The best they can be is an empty string, which you can convert to `null`/`'NULL'`.

```
if ($_POST['value'] === '') {
    $_POST['value'] = null; // or 'NULL' for SQL
}
```

Comment: Thanks deceze - I've used your answer but still having problems getting it to the right NULL - if you see me update. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alien That's not a POST/GET value, that's a *nonexistent* value.

Comment: @Bernard Well, how are you building your queries?

Comment: I'm simply pointing out this: `if ($_POST['missingKey'] === null) { /* this could get executed */ }`

Comment: Nevermind, sorted it. Removed the ' around $location_id in my SQL query and it works. Can't believe it was that simple, doh!

Comment: @AlienWebguy in this case (an HTML select) that would mean you would have to actually remove the `<select>` element or at least unset its `name` attribute with JS before submitting the form. Overkill

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a check on the post side of things.

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['type_id']) && $_REQUEST['type_id'] != 0)
    $_REQUEST['type_id'] = null;
```

Comment: That one is dangerous. What if `type_id=0` is a valid ID?

Comment: That's true. In reality, I would suggest a different approach but realistically it most likely will be too troublesome for the question asker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $type_id = ($_POST['type_id'] == '' ? "null" : "'".$_POST['type_id']."'");
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`type_id`) VALUES (".$type_id.")";
}
```

It checks if the `$_POST['type_id']` variable has an empty value.
If yes, it assign `NULL` as a string to it.
If not, it assign the value with ' to it for the `SQL` notation

Comment: PHP Syntax Error: unexpected ']' line 3

Answer (score 0):

In php 7 you can do:

```
$_POST['value'] ?? null;
```

If value is equal to '' as said in other answers it will also send you null.

Answer (score -2):

that's why Idon't like NULL values in the database at all.
I hope you are having it for *a reason.*

```
if ($_POST['location_id'] === '') {
  $location_id = 'NULL';
} else {
  $location_id = "'".$_POST['location_id']."'";
}
$notes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['notes']);
$ipid  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipid']);

$sql="UPDATE addresses 
    SET notes='$notes', location_id=$location_id
    WHERE ipid = '$ipid'";

echo $sql; //to see different queries this code produces
// and difference between NULL and 'NULL' in the query
```