# Select option NULL value or empty to not come in the request input

Tags: html

I am trying to simplify my code. I just cannot get things working the way i want.

I have 3 tables with 2 dropdown select options

1. Roadmap
2. Roadmap Years
3. Roadmap Years Releases

Selector 1 Roadmap
Selector 2 Roadmap Year

I have form with these 2 dropdowns

```
<select name="relation[id_roadmap]" id="id_portfolio" class="form-control col-auto form-control-sm autosubmit border-success" data-style="" data-width="100%">
    <option selected value="">Select Roadmap</option>
</select>

<select name="relation[id_roadmap_year]" id="id_portfolio" class="form-control col-auto form-control-sm autosubmit border-success" data-style="" data-width="100%">
    <option selected value="">Select Roadmap Year</option>
</select>
```

The other options are not relevant because i have no problem with them being set.

When i make the request with this they come empty in the input stream
How can i make the select option value to not come into the input

i've tried `<option selected value>Select Roadmap Year</option>` - this comes empty

i've tried `<option selected>Select Roadmap Year</option>` - this comes the text "Select Roadmap Year" instead of nothing.

What is the way to not come into the input stream ?
It is even possible to have them unset and not use code to unset them ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a HTML SELECT/OPTION value as NULL using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796707/is-it-possible-to-have-a-html-select-option-value-as-null-using-php)

Comment: I know, by using php or javascript before or after request works, but i dont want to use code for this. It must be a way so they won't come in the request input stream.
Just with HTML alone

And by convert into NULL it will make a query with NULL inside, that i just don't want.

Comment: Then what you wanna do is impossible. A select element in a html form will *always* cause a parameter in the POST or GET request. Look up the HTML specification .

Comment: How about datalist html tag, do you think is it possible with datalist ? to have it not come into the request ?

Comment: The same applies to input elements. They cannot be turned off in a form by just plain HTML. You have to use code somehow on the client- or serverside.

Comment: Thanks man, i didn't know there was no option to disable the inputs if they are empty just by html alone. I will keep looking maybe you are wrong :D

Im just being stubborn.

Comment: I found a way but is scuffed.

Comment: Please share it with me, if I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="relation[id_roadmap]">
<option selected="selected" disabled value="">Seleact Roadmap/option>
<option value="1">Roadmap 1</option>
</select>
```

This will not send the select value empty to the input stream

____ EDIT WITH Empty value ____

```
<select name="relation[id_roadmap]">
<option selected="selected" disabled value="">Select Roadmap/option>
<option value="">All Roadmaps/option>
<option value="1">Roadmap 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok, but a `disabled` option isn't re-selectable (unselect and than select again). It is basically a placeholder that can be forced to fill with `<select required>...</select>`.

Comment: You add another option with empty and has no disabled